# Use excel to change a Word file template

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code that sopose to take a Word file template and fill it with data from my excel table.

```
Sub CreateWordDocs()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
With Sheet1

If ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
  MsgBox "pick a different cell"
End If

DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("K2").Value
'Open File
On Error Resume Next 'if Word ia already running
Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
End If

LastRow = .Range("B999").End(xlUp).Row
    For CustRow = ActiveCell.Row To LastRow 
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False)
        For CustCol = 2 To 8
            TagName = Cells(3, CustCol)
            TagValue = Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 
            With WordDoc.Content.find
                .Text = TagName
                .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
        Next CustCol

    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("B" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
    WordDoc.SaveAs FileName

    Next CustRow
WordDoc.Display
End With
End Sub
```

when I run the code it just opens Word without creating any file....

Comment: Does your DocLoc variable include the file name to open?

Comment: yes it does  @Jenn

Comment: The first step is to turn error handling back on. After the second `End If` add a line: `On Error GoTo 0`. That way you can see what errors the code the follows generates.

Comment: Did you get the code working? I can't see your uploaded files... Where should I look for them?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming here:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
   MsgBox "pick a different cell"
End If
```

you wanted the code to stop executing if the selected cell in your Excel Worksheet was empty. If so, then you need to put a `Exit Sub` after MsgBox:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = Empty Then
   MsgBox "pick a different cell"
   Exit Sub
End If
```

I am also assuming that you have at least two Worksheets in your Excel doc because of:

- Line 5: `With Sheet1`
- Line 11: `DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("K2").Value`

It seems that you only use Sheet2 in your code to get the path of your Word Template, and everything else (Cells and Range statements) is meant to be referenced to Sheet1.

Even if the above assumptions are correct, it is not clear if you want to close the re-saved Word documents once they are filled.
If you don't close the individual Word docs once they are filled and saved, you may end up having huge amount of Word documents open depending how many Customers you have in your Excel Worksheet.
Your PC may run out of free memory, slows down very much, or who knows.

Based on the above assumptions, I made some changes in your code to make it run.

Let me know if you wanted it to do something else.

Make sure you have Microsoft Word Object Library enabled in VBA Editor, Tools -> References.

[image]

Depending on the version of your Office installed, the module to be enabled might have a different version number.

[image]

This is the complete code block after the edits:

```
Sub CreateWordDocs()

   Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow As Long
   Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
   Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object

   Dim WBook As Workbook
   Set WBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

   Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
   Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
   Set Sheet1 = WBook.Worksheets(1)
   Set Sheet2 = WBook.Worksheets(2)

   With Sheet1
      If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
         MsgBox "pick a different cell"
         Exit Sub
      End If

      DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("K2").Value

      On Error Resume Next

      'Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
      Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Err.Clear
         Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
         WordApp.Visible = True
      End If

      'LastRow = .Range("B999").End(xlUp).Row
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
      For CustRow = ActiveCell.Row To LastRow
         Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False)
         For CustCol = 2 To 8
            TagName = .Cells(3, CustCol).Value
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value
            With WordDoc.Content.Find
               .Text = TagName
               .Replacement.Text = TagValue
               .Wrap = wdFindContinue
               .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            End With
         Next CustCol
         FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("B" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
         WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
         WordDoc.Close
      Next CustRow
      'WordDoc.Display
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, but it still doesnt work... when i run the code the Word is open but without any document...

Comment: What you published initially, is that your full code? Also, are all my assumptions at the start of my answer right? Are you using 1 or two Sheets?

Comment: It worked on my PC, but there is something in your circumstances which makes a difference. Most likely you are not getting an error message because of `On Error Resume Next`, can you put in `On Error Goto 0` between `End If` and `Last row =...` , and see if you get an error message this way.

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your Excel file? How many Worksheets do you use? What are their names? Is your Word File path really stored in K2 cell on Sheet2 ? Are TagName and TagValue fed from Sheet1? All these thing were not obvious from your code... I had to guess them, so if any my guesses wrong then of course it won't work. Check them

Comment: OR if you would be happy to upload your Excel and Word Doc that would probably reveal even more about the problem...

Comment: I uploaded the files @Andras Dorko

Comment: also I did what you said and deleted "on Eror Resume Next" and now Im getting Eror on: "Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Aplication")

Comment: It failes on that line because there is no Word App running so that is not a problem.. Problem is now I wont have access to a PC for a week because I am just leaving... going on holiday... sorry.

Comment: See what happens when you comment out `set wordapp = ...`, it may work that way... then the best thing would be to put that line into an `if not getobject( , "Word.Application") = "" then`  and then that line `set 
WordApp = getobject( , "Word.Application")` and of course `End If` block, but sounds like there will be another problem later on...

Comment: Andreas, when a question isn't clear (you *assume* where the problem is) it's better to clear up exactly what the problem is in comments, rather than making the effort to create an answer and find out that wasn't the problem. You may also want to see my comment to the question about the use of error handling - you have the same problem in your suggestion that's in the OP's code - errors aren't being shown for the code that's apparently not executing.

Comment: Yes thank you... if you look at my comments that is what I suggested 17 hours ago. By the way my name is Andras. @Cindy Meister

Comment: @NoaBenNathan Please do not try to have a discussion inside an "Answer". Use the [edit] link below the question to *update the question* with new information. **HOWEVER** if the posted answer correctly answers the *original* question it should be marked as the answer and an new question asked. Stack Overflow is *not* a forum or a help desk, it's a Q&A repository.